# Using of a timer

Tags: c++, windows, api, timer

I have a c++ application and I want to call a function every 1 minute. I have this code from one friend (thanks to him)

```
void CALLBACK f(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
  printf("Hello");
}

int main() 
{
  MSG msg;

  SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000*60,(TIMERPROC) &f);
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
//Here I have the rest of my appliation
  return 0;
}
```

but I can't execute the rest of my program after the while.So, I'm searching for a solution to execute all the code and the function f every minute.

Comment: Third question about timer in this day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using windows timer messages. Your application stops at `GetMessage` until `WM_QUIT` is posted to the thread queue.

The easiest way is to use a thread and call f there, then sleep for a minute.